# magento 2 : map.xml is not ignoring the fields

Tags: php, migration, magento2, data-migration

I am trying to migrate customer and order data from the `Magento 1.9.3.3` to `Magento 2.2.6`.

I have done all the required modifications and configurations, but the only problem is there is that I am getting the error:

> source field not mapped

I have added the entries for ignoring those fields in the `map.xml` file, but even though I am getting the same error.

> error : 
>   Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'exclude_from_supply_needs' in 'field list'

```
<ignore>                
    <field>catalog_product_entity.exclude_from_supply_needs</field>
</ignore>
```

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code.  Instead, copy and paste the error message into a code or quote block in Markdown.  Thanks!

Comment: @max : can you please help with this problem